# purchaseTime in subscription with in app billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing

I am using subscription for the inapp billing and I was wondering about the purchase time in this

```
Purchase myPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(MY_SKY);
myPurchase.getPurchaseTime();
```

What would be the purchase time when subscription is used? Would it be the first date the user is subscribed to the product or is it the date of the renewal of the most recent payment?

Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My experience is that the purchase time is always the date from the first time the user made the purchase. It does not get updated when the subscription is renewed.

In [my app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.turkompisen.free.turkompisenactivity) I tell the user when the next renewal date is coming up. So I just add all the months since the purchaseTime date and present that to the user.

Answer (score -2):

As per google's documentation it will return,

```
The time the product was purchased, in milliseconds since the epoch (Jan 1, 1970) or null for none.
```

Comment: That still does not answer the question. This is subscription based and it is not one time purchase. So when they say it is purchased, do you they mean first time susbcribing or last time a payment was made (renewal)